# Обмен сообщениями между ServiceHost

Tags: c#, события, wcf, уведомления, appdomain

Подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался с подобной задачей
Вот часть (очень упрощённо ) имеющихся которые имеют hosting на WinNT службах

```
// Создание экземпляра ServiceHost #1.
serviceFirst = new ServiceHost(typeof(DomainServiceFirst));
// Начало ожидания прихода сообщений.
serviceFirst.Open();

// Создание экземпляра ServiceHost #2.
serviceSecond = new ServiceHost(typeof(DomainServiceSecond));
// Начало ожидания прихода сообщений.
serviceSecond.Open();
```

Есть необходимость передачи уведомлений между DomainServiceFirst и DomainServiceSecond
Атрибуты которыми декорирован каждый из доменных services:
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]

***Вопрос :*** есть ли внутри WCF специально заточенные для этого механизмы и если да то какие варианты из best-practice можно рассмотреть (может какой пример в internet  эту тему есть)
Спасибо.

Comment: Нужен обмен сообщениями между двумя сервисами на одной машине? Юзайте именованные пайпы: `NetNamedPipeBinding`.

Comment: Alexander Petrov  спасибо, да видимо придётся использовать стандартные механизмы например именованные каналы которые вы предложили. Хотя интересовал вопрос о готовых встроенных механизмах в WCF на эту тему. Но похоже что делать придётся  велосипед..